# Jcomponents display issue in Native look and feel

Tags: java, look-and-feel, jcomponent

I have a simple GUI which contains JButton,JMenuBar.This works fine (The display and alignment) in normal scenario but if i use below UIManager code its not proper,

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

The SSSCE for the issue i face is posted below,

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class UiManagerEx extends JFrame{
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JTextField textField;
    JLabel labl;
    JButton btn;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UiManagerEx();
    }

    public UiManagerEx() throws HeadlessException {
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Example");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        JMenuItem menuAction = new JMenuItem("ONE");
        fileMenu.add(menuAction);

        JMenuItem menu1Action = new JMenuItem("TWO");
        fileMenu.add(menu1Action);

        labl = new JLabel("Test");
        textField = new JTextField("example Program");
        btn = new JButton("enable");
        btn.setEnabled(false); // Make it true and the text will be visible.

        GroupLayout settingsLayout = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(settingsLayout);
        settingsLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        settingsLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = settingsLayout.createSequentialGroup();
        hGroup.addGroup(settingsLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(labl));
        hGroup.addGap(10);
        hGroup.addGroup(settingsLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(textField,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        hGroup.addGap(10);
        hGroup.addGroup(settingsLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(btn,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));
        hGroup.addGap(10);
        settingsLayout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = settingsLayout.createSequentialGroup();
        vGroup.addGap(10);
        vGroup.addGroup(settingsLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(labl)
                .addComponent(textField)
                .addComponent(btn));
        vGroup.addGap(10);

        settingsLayout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); //Comment this to make "alignement of JmenuItem" work properly
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
        catch (InstantiationException ex) {}
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {}
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {}

        add(panel);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        setTitle("Stack overflow");
        setResizable(true);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In native look and feel,

1. The text(enable) of Jbutton is not visisble if i make `Jbutton.SetEnabled(false)`
2. The JmenuBar display is not proper.(On click of menubar the menu items are not aligned properly).

is there any wat to get the native look and feel in my java application handling these issues.

Am new to this .. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the LookAndFeel befor creating the Objects. Then the button text is shown:
But I can not explain why. Maybe there is some initilaziton depending on LookAndFeel

```
private void init(){
 try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); // Comment this to make
                                                                           // "alignement of JmenuItem" work
                                                                           // properly
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InstantiationException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```